# MDM:iOS mdm command sending format

Tags: ios, command, mdm

I am in initial stage of MDM Server implementation, I know that when ever MDM Server wants to send the MDM Command to iOS device,Server sends push notification and then device responds back server the format of which is

PUT: /server

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>Status</key> 
       <string>Idle</string> 
       <key>UDID</key> 
       <string> [ redacted ] </string>
   </dict> 
</plist>
```

Then the MDM Server responds with whatever command has been queued up for the device, but this line is not clear to me.

I want to know if there is no as such iOS Agent application in the device,so in which format Server has to sent the command to iOS device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS MDM there is no need of iOS third party agent application because MDM Agent implementation is inbuilt with iOS platform.

If MDM Server wants to send some command to iOS device,it can use MDM push notification and after receiving the push notification iOS device , the device contacts the server,which then provides the queued command to the client.

The server link is already provided in the MDM Config profile which is installed in the iOS device while enroll.
And for communication between MDM server and iOS device plist(xml format) is used,you take the log of communication between MDM server and iOS device and you see the real time MDM plist or you can see the sample plist in MDM Protocol Reference document and see [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) pdf also.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol is explained in the following document, http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobiledevicemanagement_121211.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is provided by the MDM Protocol Reference provided by Apple. It is an XML plist.

Comment: @Abstractec..Hi Abstractec, But How to send XML plist from server as well as from device ? Please help me.